# Update first row of the selection

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with this columns `timestamp(timestamp), count(integer),name(charcter varieing)`

ther are rows in it lets say 5 rows with name "apple" and diferante timestamp and count.
I need to `update` colum `count` with `count + 1` of the row `where name = 'apple'` and first thimestamp(smallest timestamp).
How can i do this in PostgreSQL ?

I would think like this

`"UPDATE table SET count = count+1 WHERE name='apple' HAVING LEAST(timestamp)"` 
but its not working?

Answer (score 2):

This may help, however I didn't try it and maybe it can be optimized. However as it is said, premature optimization is not good.

```
UPDATE MyTABLE mt SET COUNT = COUNT + 1 
WHERE mt.NAME = 'apple' and 
mt.timestamp = (SELECT MIN(t.timestamp) FROM MyTABLE t where t.NAME = 'apple')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE table SET count = count + 1 WHERE name = 'apple' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

the ORDER BY and LIMIT clause is what "gets" the "first timestamp".

Notice that there are no sub queries or something like that, meaning the query should be executing just a simple table scan, possibly on indexed fields.

Comment: Thanks Nikoloff i am getting this eror  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ORDER"
LINE 3: ORDER BY timestamp

Comment: My bad, PostgreSQL doesn't allow ORDER BY in UPDATE statements. I'd use the code from @reader_1000's post. Sorry about misguiding you